# Loop through column, search for text

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I'm working on a `CommandButton` macro that searches a column in another worksheet for a text string and if found, adds the text "found" to a column in the original worksheet. The search text string is defined by the text in two specific cells in the original worksheet.

I've constructed some working code that finds the text within a range on another worksheet, however it is very slow when dealing with 1000's of rows. How would I convert my code to use loops in this scenario (which I presume is the quickest way to do this) ?

My current code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim artist As String
artist = ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Text

Dim title As String 
title = ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Text

Dim tick As String
tick = "found"

Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range
For Each c In Sheets("Repertoire").Range("F1:F2000")
For Each d In Sheets("Repertoire").Range("G1:G2000")

If c.Value = artist And d.Value = title Then

Sheets("Dashboard").Range("F4").Value = artist
Sheets("Dashboard").Range("G4").Value = title
Sheets("Dashboard").Range("H4").Value = tick

End If
Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered using `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: I have but I need to use the CommandButton for this task. Can `VLOOKUP` be integrated into VBA?

Comment: If you want VBA then you might want to consider using [.Find And .FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: Using `.Find` is the way to go. I've added a solution below. (*+1 for Siddharth Rout*)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for the help Alex & Siddharth!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this using `Find` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim artistFound As Range, titleFound As Range, artist As String, title As String, c As Range, d As Range

    artist = ActiveSheet.Range("C4")
    title = ActiveSheet.Range("C5")

    Set c = Sheets("Repertoire").Range("F1:F2000")
    Set d = Sheets("Repertoire").Range("G1:G2000")

    Set artistFound = c.Find(What:=artist, After:=c.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set titleFound = d.Find(What:=title, After:=d.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not artistFound Is Nothing And Not titleFound Is Nothing Then
        With Sheets("Dashboard")
            .Range("F4").Value = artist
            .Range("G4").Value = title
            .Range("H4").Value = "found"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great - however is there a way to only return the below values if artist and title are found on the same row?                           `.Range("F4").Value = artist
.Range("G4").Value = title
.Range("H4").Value = "found"`

Comment: Do you mean your criteria for a match is only if artist and title are on the same row in the sheet `Repertoire`?

Comment: Remove all references to `d` and `titleFound` and replace the `If...` line with: `If Not artistFound Is Nothing And artistFound.Offset(0, 1) = title Then`. Does that do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your real problem is the nested loops.

If you require that both artist and title appear on the same row in "Repertoire", then you need scan down the columns only once looking for the pair.

If you require that artist appears anywhere in column F and title appears anywhere in column G, then you need first scan down column F looking for artist and then scan down column G looking for the title.

In either case, you don't need nested loops.

**EDIT#1**:

Based upon your comment:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    artist = ActiveSheet.Range("C4")
    title = ActiveSheet.Range("C5")
    tick = "Found"
    Set c = Sheets("Repertoire").Range("F1:F2000")
    Set d = Sheets("Repertoire").Range("G1:G2000")
    For Each cc In c
        If cc.Value = artist And cc.Offset(0, 1).Value = title Then
            Sheets("Dashboard").Range("F4").Value = artist
            Sheets("Dashboard").Range("G4").Value = title
            Sheets("Dashboard").Range("H4").Value = tick
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next cc
End Sub
```

I used **Button1_Click** since I was using a Forms Button for de-bug.

Comment: Yeah just realised this is a bit of an issue. How do you specify with VBA that both search strings exist on the same row?

Comment: Really useful, thanks. Will upvote this answer as soon I gain some more reputation points.